# Can I send keystrokes to my USB-connected Android phone?

Tags: android

Is there any generic app for Windows and/or Andorid that enables me to send keystrokes to my USB-connected developer-enbled Android phone? Ideally it would be a toggle button that switches whether to send my keystrokes to Windows or to Android.

My use case is that I have apps that require a bit of text punching and I'd like to do that with my physical keyboard instead of my touch based phone. I do not want to physically connect my keyboard directly to my phone. It is now connected to the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ADB` for that.
You can do it drom the command line - `adb shell input text "my text"` or from "inside" the decice - open first the shell - `adb shell` and from the device's command line type `input "my text"`

Comment: perfect, just what I was looking for :)

Comment: That’s only true for SDK < 23. Android SDK 23+ does accept <space> and doesn’t require %s while you can still do it that way that’s fine but it is no longer required. No one really has any excuse outside of using someone else’s source and not understanding it to be using older SDKs seeing as they are forward compatible and as long as your source doesn’t use anything depreciated (there is usually just another method ) you wouldn’t have any issues using the latest sdk anyway.

Answer (score 0):

adb shell input text "my text"   -- will FAIL
Error: Invalid arguments for command: text
usage: input ...
       input text 
       input keyevent 
       input tap  
       input swipe

**you need to escape the following characters:**

**( ) < > | ; & * \ ~ " '** 'escaping' means putting a backslash ( \ ) before the offending character.

space is escaped by using **%s**

adb shell input text "my%stext"  -- will work